# Access/Excel 2010 Unrecognized Database Format

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, excel-2010

I have several Access 2010 databases located on a server along with one Excel 2010 file that moves data between several of these databases and a MS SQL database. These files were all created using Office 2010 and no other Office applications were installed for earlier or later years on the server that hosts these files. The Excel file runs into run-time error '-2147467259 (8004005)' when I try to open one of these Access databases.

## Relevant Information:

- I am using a ADODB connection, like so:

> ```
> Set myConn = New ADODB.Connection
> myConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
>     "Data Source=\\x-xxx-xxx\particular_location\Applications Dept\Job Tracking\Common\JobTaskTrackerActiveJobs.accdb"
> ```

- I have other Access 2010 databases located on a different virtual server that are not throwing this error when connecting to them via the same ADODB connection and provider information. This leads me to believe that it is something specific with the server computer or a corrupted file and not an issue with Access 2010 in its entirety.
- The particular Access 2010 database file was successfully compacted and repaired last night and the Excel 2010 file was running successfully all morning until it didn't. The DB file is 6,000 KB, so it's not an issue of reaching the 2GB limit.
- The last updates that were applied to this server occurred 4 days ago and it included an Excel 2010 security update, but the Excel file has been running successfully since until today.
- A user recently upgraded to Office 2016, but only has access to the frontend application, not the backend database files--could that still cause the issue between versioning?

I am not sure what the issue is that would be causing this to happen. Any help?

Comment: Is that `JobTaskTrackerActiveJobs.accdb` the backend database?

Comment: @dbmitch yes, it's one of about 10 backend databases. I ended up fixing it by reverting to a previous copy. I am still not sure what caused the error though, unless it was just corrupted in some way.